# Finite maps between algebraic varieties are closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof given by the book of Shafarevich "Basic algebraic geometry 1", section 5.3 of chapter 1, that every finite map between algebraic varieties $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ (where we assume $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$ and finite means that $k[X]$ is an integral extension of $k[Y]$), he uses that the restriction of $f$ to a closed set $Z$, $f':Z \longrightarrow \overline{f(Z)}$ is also finite. Why is this so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give a more precise reference? Why does $f(Z)$ have any sort of variety structure?

Comment: Excuse me, there was a mistake. I have fixed it, it goes to the closure of the image. I have also added a reference to the section of the book where the result appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebraically, this is the fact that if $\varphi: R \to S$ is an integral extension, then $R/\varphi^{-1}(I) \to S/I$ is again integral. This is more or less immediate to prove -- if $S$ is finitely-generated as an $R$-module, then so is $S/I$, by the same generators. And the same is true whether you think of $S/I$ as an $R$- or $R/\varphi^{-1}(I)$-module. (Here $R = k[Y], S = k[X]$ and $I = I(Z)$ in $X$.)

Geometrically, this is essentially the fact that the following maps are all finite:

- closed embeddings,
- compositions of finite maps,
- restrictions of finite maps $X \to Y$ to closed subsets of $Y$.

So $Z \hookrightarrow X \to Y$ is finite; and so is the "restriction" of $Z \to Y$ to $\overline{f(Z)}$.